# Design pattern many functions to one function to many functions implementation

Tags: java, design-patterns

Following is the flow of code:

Client Facing class:

```
class Main{
   void set(String key, String value, ...){
      wrapper.set(key, value, ..);
   }

   String get(String key, ...){
       return wrapper.get(key, ...);
   }

}
/**
 Wrapper/Facade layer which forwards the call to dao layer
 Currently Wrapper layer code looks ugly
 */
class Wrapper{
   void set(String key, String value, ...){
      executePreExecutors()
      backend.set(key, value, ..);
      executePostExecutors()
   }

   String get(String key, ...){
       executePreExecutors()
       backend.get(key, ...);
       executePreExecutors()
   }
}
 //db sdk connection classes
class backend{
    void set(String key, String value, ...){
      db.set(key, value, ..);
   }

   String get(String key, ...){
       return db.get(key, ...);
   }
}
```

Above code works fine but Wrapper does a lot of repetitive call to pre/post executors in all methods in wrapper. I want something like below but facing problem as different methods have different return types:

```
class Wrapper{
   <Return Type> wrap(input data){
      executePreExecutors();
      backend.method(input data);
      executePostExecutors();
   }
}
```

Problem I am facing is how do I generalise the above code to avoid ugly looking Wrapper layer

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question and tag, you can use Template design pattern to solve this kind of problem. Refer this wiki link.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern

You can also refer GOF pattern for Template design pattern.

Comment: How do I handle the Different type of return types from single method? for example how can in Java handle different return types like void/boolean/String. Also, since it is part of framework, it has to be extensible and do not want anyone touching this piece of code later

Comment: Define the return type as Interface, actual return type will be an implementation to that class.